# How to Get the Filter Input on Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid like this:

```
var grid = diffGrid.kendoGrid({
    autoBind: false,
    filterable: true,
    pageable: true,
    resizable: true,
    sortable: true,
    columns: [
         {
             field: "First Name",
             title: "First Name"
         }, {
             field: "Last Name",
             title: "Last Name"
         }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

How can I get the user input in the filter input textbox on either "First Name" or "Last Name" column?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it:

grid.dataSource.filter().filters[0]